# Alamofire POST request with progress

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, xcode, swift, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire to do a POST request.
As this POST request can take a while and I want to keep track of the progress and display it as a ProgressView.

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, ApiLink.create_post, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
        .progress { (bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead) -> Void in
            println("ENTER .PROGRESSS")
            println("\(totalBytesRead) of \(totalBytesExpectedToRead)")                
            self.progressView.setProgress(Float(totalBytesRead) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToRead), animated: true)
        }
        .responseJSON { (_, _, mydata, _) in 
            println(mydata)
        }
```

However, I've noticed that the **.progress block** only get called after the post request has ended instead of getting called multiple times to actually keep track of the progress.
                *println("ENTER .PROGRESSS")* gets called only once (at the end)

How can I make .progress works with Alamofire.request POST ?

Also : My parameters include a base64 encoded image string. I'm using a back-end Ruby on Rails to process the image. It's that process that is taking quite some time.

Comment: If it's just JSON you're getting back, it could very well be that the entire payload is coming back all at once... What exactly is being printed out?

Comment: Oh yeah I'm indeed getting a simple JSON request after it comes back.
The thing is that my parameters include an image base64 encoded.
I'm using a back-end Rails to process the uploaded image and this is this process that takes some time.

Comment: Unless you're doing `upload`, the progress reported is the download progress.

Comment: would you be able to tell me the difference between doing .upload (passing a NSData Image) or doing a simple .POST request with a base64 encoded image string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you can do instead is first use the `ParameterEncoding` enum to generate the HTTPBody data. Then you can pull that data out and pass it off to the Alamofire `upload` method. Here's a modified version of your same function that compiles in a playground and instead uses the `upload` function.

```
struct ApiLink {
    static let create_post = "/my/path/for/create/post"
}

let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = ["key": "value"] // Make sure this has your image as well

let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: ApiLink.create_post)!)
mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = Method.POST.rawValue

let encodedURLRequest = ParameterEncoding.JSON.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
let data = encodedURLRequest.HTTPBody!

let progressView = UIProgressView()

Alamofire.upload(mutableURLRequest, data)
         .progress { _, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
             println("ENTER .PROGRESSS")
             println("\(totalBytesRead) of \(totalBytesExpectedToRead)")
             progressView.setProgress(Float(totalBytesRead) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToRead), animated: true)
         }
         .responseJSON { _, _, mydata, _ in
             println(mydata)
         }
```

This will certainly have progress updates as @mattt originally mentioned in his comment above.

Comment: How do I retrieve the parameters in the back-end with .upload?
I'm using a rails as my back-end and all the parameters I retrieve with .request are now nil with .upload.

Comment: You probably need to package the data as a MultipartFormData object before uploading it. Until Alamofire has support for MultipartFormData uploads, you will need to use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). You could also pass the parameters in the URL and pass the data in the `HTTPBody`. It depends on what your server expects.

Comment: Hi @fabdarice, if this answer helped you solve your problem, could you mark it as such to be a good community user? Cheers.

Comment: Does this upload overload still exist?

Answer (score 1):

As ***@cnoon*** said you can use upload method to track progress with some modifications. Here is what exactly worked with me:

```
let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonObject, options: .PrettyPrinted)
Alamofire.upload(.POST, "API URL String", headers: ["Content-Type": "application/json"], data: jsonData)
         .validate()
         .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response: Response<AnyObject, NSError>) in
             //Completion handler code
         })
         .progress({ (bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) in
             //Progress handler code
         })
```

**Note** that you must set the ***"Content-Type"*** http header field value to ***"application/json"*** if the data is formatted as json to be decoded correctly at the backend.

Answer (score 0):

There's a separate method in Alamofire to upload. Please check their documentation [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire).

They have sub-sections

1. Uploading with Progress
2. Uploading MultipartFormData

Which describes uploading.